# How to use Property in Django Rest Framework model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am newbie to Django Rest Framework. I am have problem with using `Property` in Django rest framework

My Model

```py
class AwsConsoleAccess(TimeStampedModel):    

    _resources = CharField(max_length=4096)    

    @resources.setter
    def resources(self, resources: List[str]):
        self._resources = ','.join(resources)

    @property
    def resources(self) -> List[str]:
        if self._resources:
            return self._resources.split(',')

        return []
```

My serializer

```py
class AwsConsoleAccessSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AwsConsoleAccess
        fields = '__all__'
```

My view

```py
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):   
        serializer = AwsConsoleAccessSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)        
        serializer.save()
```

My curl request

```
http://localhost:8000/access/842b1012-53ef-4e98-9a20-484e681c3789

request body:
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "id": "dev-atm-jr1-platformcanary-APPLICATION"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response

```
{
    "_resources": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
status code - 400 bad request
```

If I rename the `resources` to `_resources` in request_body it does not accept the `List[str]` .

I wanted to set the List of string

Comment: use blank as: _resources = CharField(max_length=4096,blank=True)